# How to make divs appear horizontally?

Tags: html, inline

so I have created 3 divs, each acting as a navigation, however these divs stack vertically, how can I make it so that they stack horizontally? Here's the code;

HTML;

```
<div class="link">
    <!--nav-1-->        
    <div id="showmenu1" class="font-white">Click Here</div>
        <div class="menu1" id="font-white" style="display: none;">This is all some random text!</div>
    <!--nav-2-->
    <div id="showmenu2" class="font-white">Click Here</div>
        <div class="menu2" id="font-white" style="display: none;">This is all some random text!</div>
    <!--nav-3-->
    <div id="showmenu3" class="font-white">Click Here</div>
        <div class="menu3" id="font-white" style="display: none;">This is all some random text!</div>
</div>
```

CSS;

```
.link {
display: inline;
padding: 2px;
letter-spacing: 6px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about `float:left` or `inline-block`. Like in the examples down here.

```
.link div{float:left;}
```

**[DEMO float:left](http://jsfiddle.net/ySM3t/1/)**

or

```
.link div{display:inline-block;}
```

**[DEMO inline-block](http://jsfiddle.net/ySM3t/)**

Answer (score 2):

Just add `display: inline` to the div elements:

```
.link div {
    display: inline;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZyN84/

In addition, the `display: inline` within the `.link` class is not necessary unless you plan on having the container of the divs aligned with other elements in the same manner:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZyN84/1/

Answer (score 0):

Added this to your **CSS**

```
.font-white
{
    display: inline-block;
     float:left;

}
```

Changed this in your **CSS**:

```
.link {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4rzs/3/)